# Strange lines/indicators above column labels in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I think I accidentally pressed a key combo that caused a line above the column headers in Excel to show up. I can't seem to get rid of it so would someone know how I could get rid of it?

[image: Image of Excel with an unexpected bar above column headers]

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the grouping bars that grouped the data together.  They are added/disabled in the Data Tab under Outline and then Group and Ungroup options to add or delete the grouping bars.

Clear Outline option gets rid of all of them if you do not want them there at all:

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.  Marked as answer.